# Laravel - how to pass rendered component to variable?

Tags: laravel, components

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#rendering-components

Is it possible to pass rendered component to variable?
I mean something like this:

```
@php
$alert = <x-alert/> //how to get it?
@endphp

{!! $alert !!}
```

I need to have component into variable to use HTML in other variable.

---

My "real" problem:
I have a TableHelper class to generate table headers. In one header `<th>` I have `<select>` input. I want to repleace it by component `<x-inputs.select/>`

```
    {!! (new TableHelper())
    ->pushTh('wh40', 'lp.')
    ->pushThSortable('wh150', 'kod produktu', 'product_code')
    ->pushThSortable('', 'nazwa produktu', 'product_name')
    ->pushThSortable('wh70', 'ilość do pobrania', 'quantity')
    ->pushThSortable('wh70', 'stan na<br>MG', 'stock_mg')
    ->pushThSortable('wh70', 'stan na<br>PT', 'stock_pt')
    ->pushThSortable('wh70', 'stan na<br>'.Form::select('', ['' => '--', 1 => 'MG', 2 => 'PT'], null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm']), 'stock')
    ->pushThSortable('wh50', '')
    ->pushTh('wh70')
    !!}
```

The result of that is: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Ijy.png)

Answer (score 0):

No. The way the components are rendered ins't compatible with storage as a php variable. This also wouldn't be a good separation of concerns.

What are you trying to achieve that would want a component held as a variable?

Components can be used multiple times anyway, so no need for that reason.

I therefore assume it is for a conditional reason. In which case I would suggest referencing the component in a blade `@if` statement (or similar), for example:

```php
@if ($error)
  <x-alert /> 
@endif
```

It's hard to say more without more detail. Feel free to add some more code for people to review.